# RegExp to replace every second asterisk?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, e.g.:

```
"The red letters in the following words are suffixes: beauti*ful*, speech*less* and invinc*ible*."
```

I want to replace the first of each `**` pair with `<span class='red'>` and the second with `</span>`. I can do this in a for loop, but would like to know how to do it with RegExp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
s = s.replace(/\*([^*]*)\*/g, "<span class='red'>$1</span>");
```

`\*([^*]*)\*` is a little confusing, it searches for:

- `\*` - the first asterisk
- `([^*]*)` - the content between the asterisks (captures, so we can replace using `$1`.
- `\*` - the second asterisk

Working example: http://jsbin.com/isufes

Comment: @Shoe You may want to note that this also opens you up to XSS attacks.

Comment: @Shoe - no problem! There are other ways, of course, but this is the most elegant in my opinion. In general you could have tried something like http://jsbin.com/isufes/2 , but it is too complicated here.

Comment: \\*[a-zA-Z]{1,}\\* for strictly letters without anything else! you can modify to suit your need!

Comment: @Amaan - I don't see how this solution is more vulnerable to HTML injection than other solutions (or are you referring to the question in general?). You are right that if users enter these strings they should be sanitized, of course.

Comment: @Amaan. Thanks for the alert. I will investigate doing the replacement on the server to reduce XSS risks.

Comment: @Amaan - can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: @Stefano. Thanks, that is also an elegant solution.

Comment: @Kobi, I was referring to the question in general. I don't know why I commented on your answer specifically.

Comment: @nnnnnn http://jsbin.com/isufes/3/edit As you can see, if the string has some code surrounded with asterisks, it'll be executed. I was just pointing it out to the OP. (I don't know why I felt the need to close the `span` tag before injecting my script. Don't ask)

Comment: @Amaan - OK. But presumably that's only a problem if the string is entered by the user, submitted to and stored by the server without being escaped/sanitised, and then served? I don't see how the replacement makes it any worse.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah. I assumed that that's the way it was because asterisks are usually used in chat engines to make it easier to format text. It's a rookie mistake to not sanitize any fields, server-side or otherwise.